Proftpd error Unable to open config file: /etc/security/pam_env.conf
I'm getting this error in my syslog:
pam_env(proftpd:setcred): Unable to open config file: /etc/security/pam_env.conf: No such file or directory
pam_systemd(proftpd:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory
pam_succeed_if(proftpd:session): error retrieving information about user 1001

The error is shown after every disconnection from proftpd. In the ftp client I receive no error. The ftp connection works fine, the error is thrown only after disconnection and have no effect on the client. The pam_env.conf exists and have this flags:
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2971 Apr  2 18:00 /etc/security/pam_env.conf

The file is not empty but contains no uncommented lines. Here are my relevant pam/auth lines from proftpd.conf
AuthPAMConfig proftpd
AuthOrder mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c

SELinux is enabled and not throwing any error. My only SELinux flag enabled relevant to ftp is ftpd full access.
I have seen this old question which have a similar error but not identical, and have no relevant answer.
The OS is AlmaLinux 9.4.

Well, found the answer on an article from 2013.
Edit /etc/pam.d/proftpd and remove the lines:
auth    include password-auth
account include password-auth
session include password-auth

Replacing with this:
auth     include system-auth
account  include system-auth
#Comment the following line if you are having PAM issues with chrooted users
#session include system-auth

And restart with sudo systemctl restart proftpd
